# how to delete last row and show no datat displays in bootstrap table without refreshing the page in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

only last row is not getting deleted if i have 2 rows in table,and if i delete any 1 row that 1 row gets deleted and when there is only one row in table it gets deleted after refreshing the page.How to delete without refresh?.
redux action:

```
import {GET_FMP_CLIENT_REQUEST, GET_FMP_CLIENT_RESPONSE} from './index.js'

import Utils from '../../shared/utils';

const apiURL = 'fmp/admin/getAdminList';
const usr_id = Utils.getSessionStorage('usr_id');

export function getFmpAdminList(){

    let decodeValues = { 'json': JSON.stringify({'usr_id':usr_id}) }

    console.log("decodeValues-fmp",decodeValues)
    return ( dispatch ) => {
        dispatch( {type:GET_FMP_CLIENT_REQUEST} ); 
        fetch( `${Utils.getApiBaseUrl()}/${apiURL}`,  Utils.getPostOptions(decodeValues), 
            ).then( ( response ) => {
                return response.json();
             } ).then( ( retVal ) => {
                console.log("value-client-retVal",retVal) 
                if(retVal.status){ 

                    dispatch( {type:GET_FMP_CLIENT_RESPONSE, data : retVal.data} );
                }             
          } );
    }
}
```

delete function:

```
 deleteBox(usr_id) {
    const { getFmpAdminList } = this.props;
    if (usr_id != "") {
      let formValue = { 'usr_id': usr_id };
      console.log("delete formValues",formValue);
      let decodeValues ={ 'json': JSON.stringify(formValue) }
      console.log("delete decodeValues",decodeValues)
      fetch(`${Utils.getApiBaseUrl()}` + '/fmp/admin/deleteAdminTechnician',
      Utils.getPostOptions( decodeValues ),
      ).then( ( response ) => {
        return response.json();
      } ).then( ( res ) => {
        console.log("delete response",res);
        if (res.status == 1) {
          toast.success("User Deleted", {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
            autoClose: 3000
          });
          this.props.getFmpAdminList();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

```
statusFormatter = (cell,row) => { 
    return(  
            <div className="action-icons">
              <a href="#" onClick={this.toggleBox.bind(this,row.usr_id,"view")}><img src={"../"+viewimg}/></a>
              <a href="#" onClick={this.editbox.bind(this,row.usr_id,"edit")}><img src={"../"+editimg}/></a>
              <a href="#" onClick={this.deleteBox.bind(this, row.usr_id)}><img src={"../"+deleteimg}/></a>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Bootstrap table:

```
 <BootstrapTable className="work-order-table table-responsive"  data={AdminList}>
                          <TableHeaderColumn width="5%" dataField="any" dataFormat={this.indexN}>#</TableHeaderColumn>
                          <TableHeaderColumn width="25%" className="text-left" dataField='usr_first_name' dataAlign="left">Client Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                          <TableHeaderColumn width="15%" className="text-left" dataField='usr_email' dataAlign="left">Email</TableHeaderColumn>
                          <TableHeaderColumn width="15%" className="text-left" dataField='usr_created_date' dataFormat={this.createDateFormat} dataAlign="left">Created</TableHeaderColumn>
                          <TableHeaderColumn width="10%" className="text-left" dataField='usr_phone_no' dataFormat={this.campusFormatter} dataAlign="left">Contact</TableHeaderColumn>
                          <TableHeaderColumn width="20%" dataAlign="left" className="action-icons" isKey dataField='action' dataFormat={this.statusFormatter} dataAlign="left" >Action</TableHeaderColumn>
                        </BootstrapTable>
```

Comment: Where do you actually delete a value? What is `deleteBox` and where is it called from? It may be helpful to provide a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: i need delete a row from bootstrap table i can delete 2 or more rows, but when there is single row it does not get deleted only after refresh it get deleted-@DrewReese

Comment: Understood. Can you include the code that deletes the data, or better connect the dots, for us, between `deleteBox`, your redux state, and UI?

Comment: i get json from getadminlist function, i show the data in table and dispalyed ican able to display all json, i can also delete but when there is only one data i could not able to delete without refresh-@DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

Try to maintain the data as state/props. You should use state/props so that there won't be a problem while the page renders. Hit an API call to store the current available data on each row delete action and store it in state/props. This could solve your issue. Hope it helps!!.. Happy Coding..!!

Comment: Adminlist is taken as props and it is loaded in table still i need to refresh the page to delete.

Comment: Then updating AdminList will definitely reload the component. Maybe AdminList is not getting updated after API Hit success. Try to `console.log` AdminList before and after API hit.

Comment: if i have 2 or more rows for example 1 2 and 3 while deleting 2 3 it gets deleted but after that while deleting 1 it gets deleted after refresh then it shows no data display

Comment: Any other method to do this?

Comment: That is what usually happens right? deleting 2,3 will render with only one data ('1'). See let me sort it out, A component renders when a state/ props gets updated and that **updated** **value** should be used by a component  . If you're having trouble with data, rendering still, then use `componentDidMount()` to `get` and  store the data in the props on each mount. Use a get API call to store the data in props. This might help !!.